# Termplot regression plot not working

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to create a termplot in R but I'm getting an error message around undefined columns.  I've seen this example work on a video so not sure if something has changed between R versions?

```
data(airquality) #load airquality dataset
model1 <- lm(airquality$Ozone ~ airquality$Solar.R)
termplot(model1)

Error in `[.data.frame`(xx, use.rows) : undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the data frame using the `data` argument to `lm` and `termplot` will work:

```
model2 <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R, data=airquality)
termplot(model2)
```

The error is saying that `termplot`  is trying to plot one or more columns that don't exist in the data. If you look at each version of the model (see below), you can see what's going wrong: In `model1`, the coefficient name is not the same as the column name in the data frame (because it includes the data frame name), but in `model2` the coefficient name corresponds to the column name in the data frame.

```
> model1

Call:
lm(formula = airquality$Ozone ~ airquality$Solar.R)

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)  airquality$Solar.R  
           18.5987              0.1272  

> model2

Call:
lm(formula = Ozone ~ Solar.R, data = airquality)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      Solar.R  
    18.5987       0.1272
```